# How do I find and replace multiple different key-value pairs at once?

Tags: visual-studio

I have an 1000 row spreadsheet of the text I want to find and the text I want to replace it with. How do I automate this and not do a simple find and replace 1000 times?

| Text to Replace | Replacement Text |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | Apple |
| Beta | Banana |
| Gamma | Goat |

Comment: Found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Even I had stumbled into this kind of requirement. You have to also take care that bigger strings are replaced first, as smaller strings might be a prefix or suffix of bigger strings. Below is the Java code to just get it done. I know it is not convenient, and it is not what you asked, but it is an option if you are in a hurry and there are a lot of strings to be replaced.

https://github.com/overtomanu/java-util-code/blob/master/src/util/ReplaceListOfWordsInFile.java

Another option is to run the below script which is a simple bash shell script, which replaces strings in the file "EnglishCols.txt" with strings from the file "FrenchCanadianColumns.txt" in file "GenCSVFrenchCanadian.txt". This script will replace strings in the order they are listed in the file and not the bigger string first. (Tested on macOS, might have to modify the "sed" command a bit if you are running on Linux)

```bash
for i in $(seq $(cat EnglishCols.txt|wc -l));
do
  toBeReplaced=$(head -$i EnglishCols.txt|tail -1);
  replacementValue=$(head -$i FrenchCanadianColumns.txt|tail -1);
  echo replacing \"$toBeReplaced\" by \"$replacementValue\"
  sed -i '' "s|$toBeReplaced|$replacementValue|g" GenCSVFrenchCanadian.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own script for finding and replacing using visual studio code, its definitely a hack but it does actually get the job done.
To make it work:

open the consul in Visual studio code (help > developer consul)
Paste the html as the first child of the body.
open the find and replace so that both the find field and replace field are visible (so that the element selector can grab the elements (I think it works even if you only have the find field visible but nothing wrong with being extra safe :P)
the qids variable is an array of arrays with two values, the first value is the find, and the second is what to replace it with

Copy the rest of the javascript here into the consul and run.

The way it works is by updating the field values as it iterates over the array. if values were found, the replace button then exists and can be clicked. When clicked an alert displays. You must click yes for the replace to happen, or cancel to skip it. There will also be the custom modal visible. When you click yes to continue it will call the function recursively to continue replacing. This modal exists so that the script will pause for you to engage with the replace alert that visual studio brings up. (without it, it would skip past things) If you choose "no" on the custom modal, the script will stop and print what index you stopped at (so that you can modify if needed).
If you see that results were found that should be replaced but no VSC confirmation modal appeared, that likely means that the delay did not wait long enough (that waits for the search to complete, which if lines to replace are found, then makes the replace button have the attributes that match the selector in the script)

Sure its a little tedious to click yes after each replace but it gets the job done for now.

```
<div id="customModal" style="position: absolute; top: 30%; z-index: 1000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 19px; background: white; left: 45%; display: none;">
  <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
  <button id="yesButton">Yes</button>
  <button id="noButton">No</button>
</div>


function showCustomConfirmation() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    document.getElementById('customModal').style.display = 'block';

    // Attach event listeners using JavaScript
    document.getElementById('yesButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
      resolve(true);
      document.getElementById('customModal').style.display = 'none';
    });

    document.getElementById('noButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
      resolve(false);
      document.getElementById('customModal').style.display = 'none';
    });
  });
}

async function useCustomConfirmation() {
  const userResponse = await showCustomConfirmation();
  return userResponse;
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('Operation completed after ' + ms + ' milliseconds');
    }, ms);
  });
}

const find = document.querySelector('textarea[title="Search"]');
const replace = document.querySelector('textarea[title="Replace"]');
const qids = [
    ['findValue', 'replaceValue']
];
async function searchAndReplace(pair, index) {
    find.value = pair[0];
    replace.value = pair[1];
    let clicker = document.querySelector('div[title="Match Case 
(Alt+C)"].monaco-custom-checkbox')
    await clicker.click() //tried awaiting but doesnt seem to work so there is a delay right after to allow for the search to complete. Increase the time if needed
    await delay(1500)

    let execute = document.querySelector('a.action-label.codicon-replace-all[title="Replace All (Ctrl+Alt+Enter)"]')
       if (execute) {
        await execute.click()
    }
    const goNext = await useCustomConfirmation();
   if (goNext && qids[index]) {
        await searchAndReplace(qids[index], index+1)
    }
    else {
        console.log("script was cancelled or ended at index: ", index);
    }
}
await searchAndReplace(qids[0], 1)
```

Answer (score -3):

VS Code allows you to quickly find text and replace in the currently opened file. Press `Ctrl+F` to open the Find Widget in the editor, search results will be highlighted in the editor. and `Ctrl+H` for replace all your selected text.

Comment: I am not asking how to perform a simple find and replace, i am asking how to execute multiple find and replaces at once

Comment: you try this [link]https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor

Comment: also not what I asked